# Debugging TypeScript on VSCode

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug the following typescript code using Visual Studio Code:

```
class Student {
    fullname : string;
    constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname) {
        this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

console.log(greeter(user));
```

This is my launch.json configuration file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    // List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
            "name": "TypeScriptDebugTest",
            // Type of configuration.
            "type": "node",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
            "program": "./HelloWorld.ts",
            // Automatically stop program after launch.
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            // Command line arguments passed to the program.
            "args": [],
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
            "cwd": ".",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
            // Environment variables passed to the program.
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
            "sourceMaps": true,
            // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
            "outDir": "./built"
        }
    ]
}
```

The javascript compiled files are in a built folder under the root directory. When I try to debug the same error keeps ocurring: **"Cannot connect to runtime process(timeout after 5000ms)"**

Note: I want to debug the .ts file, not the compiled javascript.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank You!

Comment: Is this with node 4.x?

Comment: Yes @BenjaminPasero I am using node 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Support for debugging node 4.x is coming in our next release. Stay tuned!

Comment: Does this mean 0.10.0 beta? I'm having the same issue trying to debug a VSCod extension with Node v4.2.1 in vscode 0.10.0